# Passing complex object to rails action via Unirest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unirest

I have a simple controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def test_action
    render plain: "OK"
  end
end
```

And I'm posting to the action via a separate ruby file using Unirest:

```
require 'unirest'

resp = Unirest.post "localhost:3000/test_action.json", 
                    headers:{ "Accept" => "application/json" }, 
                    parameters:{ foo: 1, my_list: [{foo: 1}, {foo: 2}] }

puts resp.body
```

When I run this I see the following in my rails console:

```
Parameters: {"foo"=>"1", "my_list"=>{"foo"=>"2"}}
```

Why is the first item in my_list missing?  How can I get it to appear?  Should I be using something other than Unirest for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with hashes the second key value will overwrite the first. `foo: 2` gets read last and is the last assignment for foo. If you want the first item to appear you should rename it to `[{"foo1":"1"}, {"foo2": 2}]`